# Start django shell with a temporary database

Tags: django, django-tests

I want to fire up the django shell with a temporary database (like what's done when doing django tests)

Is there any command like:

```
python manage.py testshell
```

where I can create a bunch of bogus models without polluting my database?

Comment: IIRC, the unit testing framework creates the test DB for you. You just have to make sure it has the right permissions to do so.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Nevermind, this [blog post](http://testedwebdev.blogspot.com/2012/05/django-shell-testing.html) explains it

```
>>> from django import test
>>> test.utils.setup_test_environment() # Setup the environment
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> db = connection.creation.create_test_db() # Create the test db
```

Comment: Even though you answered it yourself, mark this answer as correct so this doesn't show up as an unanswered question.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone I have 2 more days until I can do that, but will do.

Comment: Ah, forgot about the delay.

Comment: The blog link is invalid, but I think the commands are adequate for a test shell. Maybe the two commands `connection.creation.destroy_test_db()` and `test.utils.tear_down_test_environment()` are also helpful.

Comment: Use `db = connection.creation.create_test_db(keepdb=True)` if you want to connect to an existing database and you're using Django >= 1.8. Docs are [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/advanced/#django-db-connection-creation).

Answer (score -2):

You could just turn autocommit off:

```
from django.db import transaction
transaction.set_autocommit(False)
```